# print star or "X" patterns

Tags: c, loops

Please help me finish my homework.
I would like to produce pattern like this using looping c language

```
X X X
 XXX 
XXXXX
 XXX
X X X

XXXXX
X   X
X   X
X   X
XXXXX

X
XX
X X
X  X
XXXXX

    X
   XX
  X X
 X  X
XXXXX
```

this is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
for(int i=1;i<=26;i++){
    if(i==1){
        for(int a = 1;a<=5;a++){
            if(a==1 || a==3 || a==5){
                printf("X");
            }
            else{
                printf(" ");
            }
        }  
    }
    else if(i==2){
        for(int b = 1;b<=5;b++){
            if(b==2 || b==3 || b==4){
                printf("X");
            }
            else{
                printf(" ");
            }
        }
    }
    else if(i==3){
        for(int c = 1;c<=5;c++){
            printf("X");
        }  
    }
    else if(i==4){
        for(int d = 1;d<=5;d++){
            if(d==2 || d==3 || d==4){
                printf("X");
            }
            else{
                printf(" ");
            }
        }  
    }
    else if(i==5){
        for(int e = 1;e<=5;e++){
            if(e==1 || e==3 || e==5){
                printf("X");
            }
            else{
                printf(" ");
            }
        }  
    }
    else if(i==8){
        for(int f = 1;f<=5;f++){
            printf("X");
        }  
    }
    else if(i==9){
        for(int g = 1;g<=5;g++){
            if(g==1|| g==5){
                printf("X");
            }
            else{
                printf(" ");
            }
        }  
    }
    else if(i==10){
        for(int h = 1;h<=5;h++){
            if(h==1|| h==5){
                printf("X");
            }
            else{
                printf(" ");
            }
        }  
    }
    else if(i==11){
        for(int jtmp = 1;jtmp<=5;jtmp++){
            if(jtmp==1|| jtmp==5){
                printf("X");
            }
            else{
                printf(" ");
            }
        }  
    }
    else if(i==12){
        for(int f = 1;f<=5;f++){
            printf("X");
        }  
    }
    else if(i==15){
        for(int k = 1;k<=5;k++){
            if(k==1){
                printf("X");
            }
            else{
                printf(" ");
            }
        }  
    }
    else if(i==16){
        for(int l = 1;l<=5;l++){
            if(l==1 || l==2){
                printf("X");
            }
            else{
                printf(" ");
            }
        }  
    }
    else if(i==17){
        for(int m = 1;m<=5;m++){
            if(m==1 || m==3){
                printf("X");
            }
            else{
                printf(" ");
            }
        }  
    }
    else if(i==18){
        for(int n = 1;n<=5;n++){
            if(n==1 || n==4){
                printf("X");
            }
            else{
                printf(" ");
            }
        }  
    }
    else if(i==19){
        for(int o = 1;o<=5;o++){
            printf("X");
        }  
    }
    else if(i==22){
        for(int p = 1;p<=5;p++){
            if(p==5){
                printf("X");
            }
            else{
                printf(" ");
            }
        }  
    }
    else if(i==23){
        for(int q = 1;q<=5;q++){
            if(q==4 || q==5){
                printf("X");
            }
            else{
                printf(" ");
            }
        }  
    }
    else if(i==24){
        for(int r = 1;r<=5;r++){
            if(r==3 || r==5){
                printf("X");
            }
            else{
                printf(" ");
            }
        }  
    }
    else if(i==25){
        for(int s = 1;s<=5;s++){
            if(s==2 || s==5){
                printf("X");
            }
            else{
                printf(" ");
            }
        }  
    }
    else if(i==26){
        for(int t = 1;t<=5;t++){
            printf("X");
        }  
    }
    else{
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}
```

but my code so long not simple, because i'm so newbie
but i want simple code using method like this

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main()
{
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
                if (j == 1 || j == 5 || i == 1 || i == 5)
                    printf("X");
                else
                    printf(" ");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
XXXXX
X   X
X   X
X   X
XXXXX
```

Comment: Are you sure this i c++ code and not c?

Comment: is not homework a learning opportunity? why would someone want to rob you of it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i mean c, sorry

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: In the case of box, the condition was simple (based on constants): `if (j == 1 || j == 5 || i == 1 || i == 5)`. In the case of a triangle, (I would continue on this as I feel it has next higher level of "handicap") the condition has to be based on the relation of `i` and `j` to each other. Any idea? (May be, start with horizontal and vertical bar first. If you got it running for an "L", then think about the diagonal line.)

Answer (score 0):

You would really benefit from using functions. Before your main program declare a function for each shape e.g.

```
function square()
{
       for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
                if (j == 1 || j == 5 || i == 1 || i == 5)
                    printf("X");
                else
                    printf(" ");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Now in your main program you can write :-

```
main()
{
 square();
 square();
 triangle();
 star();
 triangle();

 return 0;
}
```

When you have done that read about **parameters**. Then you will be able to write :-

```
main()
{
 square(2);
 triangle(1);
 star(1);
 triangle(1);

 return 0;
}
```

to do exactly the same thing. he he... square(128); should be fun ;)